# How to get/publish multi-module maven project site into a folder

Tags: java, maven, github-pages, maven-site-plugin

I have multi-module maven project. I can see generated project dosumentation after `mvn site`, but it is in every module `target` folder.

**how to get  maven project site into one folder?** 
(I don't really need to deploy, I will put generated site manually into GitHub pages.)

Plugin docs:

http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-site-plugin/

References `<distributionManagement>` `<site>` section, but there is no trace how to make output into a defined folder. 
Also tried `mvn site:jar` - it make .jar again in every module `target`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend to use the [site-maven-plugin](https://github.com/github/maven-plugins) following part to distribute generated sites to github:

```
<profile>
  <id>github</id>
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>com.github.github</groupId>
        <artifactId>site-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>0.8</version>
        <configuration>
          <message>Creating site for ${project.version}</message>
          <server>github</server>
        </configuration>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>site</goal>
            </goals>
            <phase>post-site</phase>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>

</profile>
```

To preview your site before publishing you can use the [stage goal of maven-site-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-site-plugin/usage.html#Staging_a_Site) like this:

```
mvn site:stage -DstagingDirectory=C:\fullsite
```

Comment: Looks fine, though the question may be how to preview site with all links working, before publishing.

Comment: Updated answer accordingly.